# Ubuntu 14.04: How to install specific version of nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I used the following commands to install nodeJS version 8.x

```
1. sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
2. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
3. sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

When I run the command

```
node -v
```

it shows v4.2.6 instead of the latest 8.x versions. Here is a screenshot.

[image: NodeJS Installation]

Answer (score 7):

First install [Node.js via `apt-get`](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) (e.g. v8):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Once you have installed Node.js, use the npm package [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to switch to any version:

> Simply execute `n <version>` to install a version of node. If `<version>`
>   has already been installed (via `n`), `n` will activate that version.

Install `n` as global package and use `n` to install the latest version of Node.js:

```
npm i -g n
n latest
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Let me know why, and I would love to improve my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) to handle multiple nodejs versions.

**Installing nvm**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

or

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

**Installing node**

```
nvm install <version>
```

**Using desired version**

```
nvm use <version>
```

Comment: nvm not installing with the curl command. Getting this error:

"You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout."

Comment: Try with wget. You can check the complete guide in GitHub.

Comment: Worked with wget. Thanks a ton Ivan!!